# Using writefile() to create a Json file, inquirer, and editing the results

Tags: node.js

I created a file with writefile() 
Using inquirer to input a certain data that would ask for name, age, occupation from command line into the created file, it works well, now what I need help is how to readfile() edit and replace the name age occupation the created Json file and if the answer isn’t given it’ll be left on the former answers.

I’m afraid I might not be explainig it well, help.

```
inquirer = require('inquirer')
var fs = require('fs');


var question = answer();


inquirer.prompt(question).then(answers => {
    fs.writeFile("input.json", JSON.stringify(answers),function (err){
        console.log(err)
    })})



function answer() {
    return [{
        type: 'input',
        name: 'name',
        message: "What's your name?",
        default: 'name'
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        name: 'age',
        message: "how old are you?",
        default: 'age',
    },{
        type: 'name',
        name: 'occupation',
        message: "What's your occupation?",
        default: 'occupation'
    }];
}
fs.readFile("input.json"),function (err){
    console.log(err)}
```

Comment: Please note that the site requires that you try to solve the  problem yourself first and once you run into issues, the community will be happy to help. As such please provide some relevant sample code of your attempts to readfile and indicate where you are having issues

Comment: done with the edit, please check.